# Return True if Date and False if no

Tags: python, datetime, format

i have a task:

```
click_id   click_timestamp
1          '02/12/2023'
2          '02/12/2023'
3          '02/12/2023'
4          '02/12/20233'
5          '02/12/2023]'
```

the matter is understand and tag(probably in new column 'Validate) with lambda is it Date or not

```
click_id   click_timestamp  Validate
1          '02/12/2023'     True
2          '02/12/2023'     True
3          '02/12/2023'     True
4          '02/12/20233'    False
5          '02/12/2023]'    False
```

i tried with lambda, but i don't know how to get true or false
THX

Comment: Assuming you have a pandas DataFrame, you need to convert date to pd.to_datetime first. Then you can query with exact date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call the datetime string conversion and check for errors:

```
import datetime

def func(d):
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(d, r'%d/%m/%Y')
        return True
    except:
        return False
        

df['Validate'] = df['click_timestamp'].map(func)
```